# CallLog.Calls._COUNT

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In  Android documentation (Content Providers) CallLog.Calls._Count is part of BaseColumns, but logcat says invalid column _COUNT when run this code:

```
    String[] projection = new String[] { CallLog.Calls._COUNT };

    Cursor cursor = this.getContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

Please see this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1343

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in only the number of rows in the directory, you don't need to project the `_COUNT`, try this:

```
int count;
Cursor cursor = this.getContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToLast())
   count = cursor.getPosition();
```

I'm not sure if you can find `_COUNT` column in `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`. If you are not satisfied with my answer above, try finding all column names in the `Cursor` by iterating column indexes.